# Setting touchpad like graphic table

Tags: touchpad, xserver, xinput, libinput

I'm trying to set my touchpad in absolute mode, i need that to work like a graphic table, i know that exist FingerPainter but i don't searching that.

```
xinput set-mode 13 ABSOLUTE
```

The command throws that, i searched for hours but i didn't find nothing of my problem, how i can fix that? Thank you, really, than you all

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  5 (X_SetDeviceMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  19
```

EDIT: Sorry i forgot put my hardware and software settings, there is
Touchpad:
[Touchpad - ELAN0752:00 04F3:31C2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0sXQ.png)
[OS - Ubuntu 22.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnQr2.png)

Comment: There is no information about Ubuntu version or the touchpad model.

Comment: I put the info, sorry